# Sharing entities between the frontend and the backend with entities library

Tags: node.js, typescript, architecture, microservices, software-design

In our monorepo we share the same entities with a library we have created. In that way, there is a single source of truth, which is the library, and the frontend and the backend consume it.

Currently, the library contains ALL the entities of the project.

Current situation:

```
Microservice A
  frameworks
  contracts
  ...
```

```
Libraries
  entities
   microservice-a-entities
    x
    y
  ...
```

In order to maintain transparency and understanding, in each microservice at the backend I want to add an `entities` directory and import from the `entities` library the corresponding and relevant entity to the microservice. In that way, I can find the relevant entities for the microservice in one place, in the microservice itself, without searching for the entities in the `entities` library.

The desired approach:

```
Microservice A
  frameworks
  contracts
  entities
   x - imports x entity from entities library
   y - imports y entity from entities library
  ...
```

```
Libraries
  entities
   microservice-a-entities
    x
    y
  ...
```

Is it a good approach? It's kind of the Barrel Exports approach, no?

Answer (score 3):

So, the issue with this is that you haven't created microservices, you have created a distributed monolith.  The backend and frontend can't change independently, they will be coupled with this library of entities, and effectively be a single "thing".  Furthermore, by sharing these entities across your microservices, you are coupling them to each other.  Nothing will be able to change without everything being redeployed and retested.

This might be fine.  A monolith is often the right solution for most classes of problems, but at that point, give up on the microservices, and just deploy the thing as a monolith.  The path you are heading down will give you all the disadvantages of a monolith plus all the disadvantages of microservices, pick one or the other and take those advantages.

Monolith Pros:

- Have consistent domains (like you are trying for)
- Strong, centralized validation of entity rules
- Transactional consistency is generally straightforward
- Are generally easy to deploy and grow

Monolith Cons:

- You have to update all aspects of the system at once (to keep consistency)
- Can't easily scale different parts of the system independently (have to scale the whole thing)

Microservices Pros:

- Can have completely decoupled teams working on different aspects of the software
- Scales independently
- Can utilize different technologies for different parts of the system

Microservices Cons:

- Much more complexity in deployment
- Slower than in-process communication (like, much slower)
- Will cost more per feature because of inter-team communication
- Much harder to achieve transactional consistency